# What makes the elements of sigma algebra measurable (and measurable w.r.to which measure)?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm familiar with the definition of sigma algebra defined over a set, which is a collection of subsets that is closed under countable unions and also under complements. While reading about probability theory, it was mentioned that by limiting ourselves to the sigma-algebra, we are avoiding some pathological behaviours caused by what are called as non-measurable sets.

1. From the definition of sigma algebra, I don't see how it only consists of measurable sets. Is it an implication of the definition? If yes, how is it avoiding admitting non-measurable sets into sigma algebra?
2. When they say measurable/non-measurable, what is the measure they are talking about? Lebesgue, counting, probability? It seems there is an implicit measure every time someone says a set is measurable/non-measurable.
3. Can anyone give an example of a set which is measurable w.r.to one measure but not w.r.to another measure?
4. How important is it to really worry about sigma algebras and measurable/non-measurable sets?
   Most of the continuous distributions are defined on real line and almost every subset of real line that I can think of is a part of sigma algebra and has a definite measure on it.  It feels like these concepts are mostly used in definitions to have a concrete theory of probability. I don't remember needing any of those concepts while working with probability/random variables. Are these concepts only useful in developing further theory of probability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is by the definition of measure (see @DEATH_CUBE_K 's answer)
2. If not specified, it is usually the Lebesgue measure. If you are dealing with a random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)\to\mathbb{R}$, the measure might be $P\circ X^{-1}$ given by its cumulative distribution function.
3. [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) $V$ are non-measurable w.r.t. Lebesgue measure,but are measurable w.r.t. cardinal measure (i.e. $\operatorname{card}(V)=\infty$)
4. Non-measurable sets are constructed in a "non-constructive" way (using Axiom of Choice), so it is understandable that you never meet such sets in real-life applications. From a theoretically point of view, Ulam's theorem says that one cannot extend a continuous measure on real line such that all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable, in particular there are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not measurable Lebesgue. Working witn non-measurable sets leads to pathological behavior, such as [Banach–Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox). You may also read [Non-measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set), it gives more information.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space, that is, $X$ is a non-empty set, and $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, and $\mu: \Sigma \to [0,\infty]$ is a measure. By definition, a set $E \subset X$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$ if and only if $E \in \Sigma$, i.e., we declare which sets are to be measurable by constructing $\Sigma$. Thus, a set is not measurable if it does not belong to $\Sigma$.
2. When we say a set is measurable or non-measurable, we always have the measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ in mind. Sometimes the measure space can be understood from the context.
3. If two measures $\mu, \nu$ are defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra, say $\Sigma$, then there exists no set which is $\mu$-measurable by not $\nu$-measurable. So you would need to be looking at totally different measure spaces which makes the question somewhat enlightening.

Comment: Does the third point of your answer means that every element of sigma algebra is measurable no matter what measure we choose? or that sigma-algebra changes based on the measure we choose? My understanding is that construction of sigma-algebra has no dependency on the measure we choose and the definition of measure is already assuming that $(X, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space. Is there an explanation to why elements of $\Sigma$ are measurable without this assumption?

Comment: @VamshiKumarKurva Yes. Whenever we think of a measure, we must understand its domain. A measure is a function $\mu:\Sigma \to [0,\infty]$ and the domain of definition $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Again, we call the elements of $\Sigma$ measurable sets (by definition). So, if we define two different measure $\mu,\nu$ on the **same** $\sigma$-algebra, then of course they have the same measurable sets.

Comment: @momo gives an example of two meaures defined on **distinct** $\sigma$-algebras, namely Lebesgue measure defined on $\mathcal{L}$, the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and the cardinal measure which is defined on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. The Vitali set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ but can be shown to not be an element of $\cal{L}$.

Comment: @Vamshi Kumar Kurva you are right to be confused. In the most interesting cases (e.g. Lebesgue measure) $\Sigma$ is not given, but it is constructed from the measure itself using Caratheodory extension theorem. In other words, 1) the Lebesque measure is defined first on intervals as being the length of the interval, then 2) trivially extended to the algebra generated by the intervals, then 3) extended to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the previous algebra, and finally 4) extended to the completion of the previous $\sigma$-algebra, such that any subset of a negligible set is also negligible.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm really confused. So, this is my bottomline understanding. $\sigma$-algebra is constructed using open sets and open sets have a definite measure (no matter what measure we choose), so the unions, intersections and complements of open sets also have a definite measure and hence $\sigma$-algebra is measurable w.r.to any measure. If we construct a $\sigma$-algebra this way, vitali set can never be a part of our $\sigma$-algebra. Is that right?